# c# Linq Keywords?

Tags: c#, linq, notepad++, keyword

I'm adding more keywords to notepad++'s C# Syntax highlighting and it would really help if i had a complete list of LINQ keywords for c#.

Comment: Check out the **C# 3.0 Language Specification Section 7.15: Query Expressions**.

Comment: More useful informatioin for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/11/reserved-and-contextual-keywords.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From memory:

```
from select where join on equals group by orderby ascending descending into let
```

EDIT: As Eric says, you may want to include `var` as well (you certainly should if you want to highlight all C# 3 contextual keywords).

If you're doing symbols too, you may want to include a pattern for `=>`

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad: there was bound to be one I'd forgotten :)

Comment: Accepting this one cause i can copy-paste right into the xml file :)

Comment: Nice Jon. Of course, "where" was not added originally as a LINQ contextual keyword, it was added as a contextual keyword for generic constraints, so now it is a contextual keyword twice over! It is debatable whether "var", which you omit, should be counted as a "LINQ keyword". It was added for LINQ scenarios but is not part of the query comprehension syntax.

Comment: Yes, my natural translation of the question was "what are the keywords for query expressions" - I hadn't even considered `var`...

Answer (score 7):

You can get started [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Linq Query keywords [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx).